# Cisco AnyConnect secure mobility client home network win7 x64

Tags: windows-7, cisco-anyconnect

does anyone know how to disable "cisco anyconnect secure mobility client" in register. Problem is that I cannot get to work business laptop on my home wifi..

The version of the client is 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

To turn off the "AutoConnectOnStart" please add the previous piece of code to the XML profile:

```
<AutoConnectOnStart UserControllable="true">false</AutoConnectOnStart>
```

The XML profile can be found in the following path:

- Windows 7 and Vista

  `C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile\`
- Windows XP

  `C:\Document and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile`

**Mac OS X and Linux**

```
`/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/`
```

[Source](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2179036)

Also you can disable the autostartup-entry in msconfig.

1. Type in the start-field `msconfig`
2. Go to the tab "startup"
3. Disable the AnyConnect-entry

Comment: Hmmm, I don't want disable autostart, I just want to manually disable in windows that I can connect at home to my home network and then manually enable it again -> I want that everything is working ok when I'm back to company.

Comment: So you want to disable the client? Can't you just stop the service from the tray-icon or stop the process in the task-manager?

Comment: Hmmm I have diffrent screen as you show me.

http://postimg.org/image/52p8n5p2b/
http://s14.postimg.org/kyv2tbynl/Capture1.png

Comment: Which version do you have?

Comment: Ah I see. I've deleted the screenshot because it's for an other version.

Comment: I would recommend you to disable the client in the tray-icon or to stop the process

Comment: I can disable "network service" inside of "anyconnect secure mobility client", but still not working via cable or wifi..

Comment: so no solution ??

Comment: I don't understand your problem i think. Do you want to disable the VPN client?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, if I disable in windows this client my home network is not working, after I restart PC, this client automatically turns on. Maybe is this a problem that after I disable client I need to restart PC + disable autostart in XML and then will my home network working ?

Comment: Is it also possible to "turn off" this autostart in register ?

Comment: yes then VPN client-. at home I don't need any client to use my local network, just plug cable in laptop and it should work...

Comment: Lets go to the chat. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10878/discussion-between-chris-and-micky)

Answer (score -1):

Short answer.

**From Command prompt**

**To Restart:** `net stop vpnagent` and `net start vpnagent`

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.